# Can I override a ssh host configuration with a custom hostname?

Tags: ssh

When having a ssh host configuration ...

```
Host myhost
   Hostname 192.168.1.1
   User     myuser
   Port     1234
```

... I can override the username with `ssh otheruser@myhost`.

Can I also override the hostname? I want ssh to use the configuration from `myhost`, but connect to another Hostname/ip address than `192.168.1.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
ssh -o Hostname=actual_host_name myhost
```

The relevant documentation:

From [ssh_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> [ssh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1) obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (*~/.ssh/config*)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (*/etc/ssh/ssh_config*)
>
> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.

From [ssh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1):

> [**-o**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#o) option
> Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration file. This is useful for specifying options for which there is no separate command-line flag. ...

Again, from [ssh_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> [**Hostname**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Hostname)
> Specifies the real host name to log into. This can be used to specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts. ... The default is the name given on the command line.